# Switch between activities in android app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android app where I need to implement show and hide functionalities.

Assume my first activity is Activity A. This has a show button which will open Activity B. Activity B has a 'X' button which will 'minimize' this activity and go to Activity A. Clicking on the show button will show Activity B.

In Activity B, I have a list view. Clicking on any, will open up Activity C. Now there is another functionality which will hide both activity C and B and show Activity A. If we click on show button, it should take the user to Activity C maintaining the stack i.e. C -> B -> A

To implement the above two functionalities, I was finishing the activities during hide and creating again during show. I don't want to do this as I want to have the previous state when I show the activities again.

I am thinking of the below:

1. To implement 'X' functionality, I will use `ActivityB.moveTaskToBack(`) while hiding and will use the below code while showing it again:

   `Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
   startActivity(i);`
2. To implement hiding activities C and B and showing them back is creating few problems. Can I follow the above approach on B and C? Will it work?

Is there any better solution to handle above two requirements?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use `Fragments` in this case which are specially designated for this purpose

```
boolean visitedC;
```

**In Activity A onCreate**

```
FragmentA a = new FragmentA();
fragmentTransaction.replace(a).addToBackStack("a").commit();
vistedC = false;
```

**a -> click on show**

```
FragmentB b = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("b");
if(b == null)
b = new FragmentB();
fragmentTransaction.replace(b).addToBackStack("b").commit();
```

**FragmentB oncreate**

```
if(visitedC){
      FragmentC c = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("c");
      if(c == null)
      c = new FragmentC();
      fragmentTransaction.replace(c).addToBackStack("c").commit();
    }
```

**b -> click on x**

```
visitedC = false;
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

**b -> click list item**

```
FragmentC c = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("c");
if(c == null)
c = new FragmentC();
fragmentTransaction.replace(c).addToBackStack("c").commit();
```

**c -> click X**

```
visitedC = true;
fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("a", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Activity B contains 4 tabs which are fragments. The team wants to treat B and C as activities. So is there any solution for this? Will my solution work?

Comment: Yes, `Fragment` is lighter version of `Activity`, you can add `viewpager` inside a `FragmentB`, that's the beauty of it